# Get rid of all redirects and "non-api" behavior in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm currently facing some issues when using Laravel as API-only backend. I want to develop the front-end separately and therefore treat Laravel as an API only. I have issues when writing tests. I'm still using the web middleware group (not API), and when using the `auth` middleware, everything works when testing with postman for example, but when writing a test.

**Example**

```php
public function search_competitions_unauthorized ()
{
    $response = $this->get('/competitions/ABCDEFG');

    $response->assertStatus(401);
}
```

The endpoint `/competitions/ABCDEFG` is protected by the auth middleware.

I receive a 500 as response code because there is no route with the name `login` defined. This is easy to solve (create a route with name login), but I want Laravel to treat every request as an API request that does not have any redirects.

I've tried a few things to get rid of this behavior.

I've defined a new class "DefaultRequest" that extends `Illuminate\Http\Request`

```php
class DefaultRequest extends Request
{
    public function expectsJson()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function wantsJson()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I changed the index.php in the public folder.

```php
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = App\Http\Requests\DefaultRequest::capture()
);
```

Also, all the requests used in my controllers use this as their default. As I had the same issue with request validation, I've also added this method to my default request.

```php
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
}
```

I have the feeling that this should've been easier to resolve. It seems like in general, this would only be a problem for me while testing, and that I could set specific headers in my tests. But I wanted to disable all these redirect behaviors as I NEVER want these for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by placing request type check in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    ...
    // handling unauthenticated requests
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException) {
        if (
            $request->wantsJson() ||
            $request->expectsJson() ||
            array_get($request->route()->action, 'prefix') == 'api'
        ) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I understand this is a valid solution , but I'm actually looking for an option to enforce a json response everywhere, not only for specific exception types.

Comment: Well, apart from exceptions everything should be handled by your resource controllers.
You can create ApiController with respond method, like so:
   `protected function respond($data, $statusCode = 200, $headers = [])`
    `{`
        `return response()->json($data, $statusCode, $headers);`
    `}`

And just inherit from it in every other controller.